# How to get an index of an element inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexof

I am trying to get the index of an element inside an object like below:

```js
var array = [{spot_id: 6, spot_no: 6, gate_id: 6}, {spot_id: 16, spot_no: 17, gate_id: 5}, {spot_id: 5, spot_no: 5, gate_id: 5}, {spot_id: 11, spot_no: 11, gate_id: 5}, {spot_id: 15, spot_no: 16, gate_id: 4}, {spot_id: 4, spot_no: 4, gate_id: 4}, {spot_id: 10, spot_no: 10, gate_id: 4}, {spot_id: 14, spot_no: 15, gate_id: 3}, {spot_id: 9, spot_no: 9, gate_id: 3}, {spot_id: 3, spot_no: 3, gate_id: 3}, {spot_id: 8, spot_no: 8, gate_id: 2}, {spot_id: 13, spot_no: 14, gate_id: 2}, {spot_id: 2, spot_no: 2, gate_id: 2}, {spot_id: 7, spot_no: 7, gate_id: 1}, {spot_id: 12, spot_no: 13, gate_id: 22}];


var result = array.reduce( (acc, o) => (acc[o.gate_id] = (acc[o.gate_id] || 0)+1, acc), {} );

console.log(result)
let index = result.findIndex(rank => rank === 4);
```

but it fails. I think `findIndex` is only for arrays and not objects.

Here is this example in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnyeudzr/32/):

Expected output:

For example if I want to compare the index of one of the elements with a number and  see if its true (exists) like:

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
if (result[i] === 22) return true; //here I am checking the value but I want to actually compare the index of result not its value.
}

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Are you trying to find the `gate_id` that appeared 4 times within `array`? If not, can you clarify what the end result should be? You are correct that `findIndex` is not defined on the objects in your array.

Comment: An object is an unordered collection of key-value pairs, hence there's no "index"

Comment: @User863 check the updated question

Comment: @Andreas but is there any way to find the indexes?

Comment: There's no "index" in an object

Comment: @Andreas key?!?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0):

findIndex is only for arrays and not objects, right.
You can use something like:

```
let index= Object.keys(result).find(key=> result===4)
```

or simply,

```
let index;
if(result[4])
    index = 4
```

Comment: try doing this and you see this is wrong: `let index= Object.keys(result).find(key=> result[key]===22)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you're trying to see how many items are there with `gate_id === 22`. In that case all you need is:

```
result[22];
```

which is `1`.